# Pandas Dataframe from Cloud Functions to BigQuery - only PARQUET and CSV source_formats?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm querying an API with GCP Cloud Functions and would like to write the result to BigQuery. I'm getting this error:

> Got unexpected source_format: 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'. Currently, only PARQUET and CSV are supported

This is my code

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd
import requests
import datetime

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
 
 response = requests.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=berlin&appid=12345&units=metric&lang=de")
 responseJson = response.json()
 
 # Creates DataFrame
 df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':pd.to_datetime(format(datetime.datetime.now())),
               'name':str(responseJson['name']),
               'temp':float(responseJson['main']['temp']),
               'windspeed':float(responseJson['wind']['speed']),
               'winddeg':int(responseJson['wind']['deg'])
               }, index=[0])  

 project_id = 'myproj'
 client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)
 dataset_id = 'weather'

 dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
 job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
 job_config.autodetect = True
 job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND"
 job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
 load_job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, dataset_ref.table("weather_de"), job_config=job_config)
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: option 1 - stream to BigQuery; option 2 - save data as object in a Cloud Storage bucket, and (2a) - start a 'load job' (2b) use BigQuery data transfer; option 3 - use csv format, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The BigQuery client library reference states that this is [intended behavior](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_dataframe) when loading into a table from a dataframe using `load_table_from_dataframe()`:

> By default, this method uses the parquet source format. To override this, supply a value for source_format with the format name. Currently only CSV and PARQUET are supported.

Something you can try is replacing that method with `load_table_from_json()`, which is also [available](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_json), and uses NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON as the source format. This method clearly will not accept a dataframe as input, so I could recommend using a JSON object to store the data you need from the API response. Otherwise, you can convert the existing dataframe you created to json using the `to_json()` method from the [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html).

You can read more into how the BigQuery client works from the [reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client), and you can also see the built [source formats](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.SourceFormat.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.SourceFormat).